# how to search a node and highlight it

Tags: d3.js

First of all thanks a lot everyone for helping me through my d3 projects.

i am trying to develop a search feature for a visualization created by d3.js The nodes are circles and have a class .node an attribute code="12311", code="12312"...and so on

I am trying to have a scenario where the input value if matches with the attribute then that perticular node color will change or some type of filter.

The nodes look like this

```
<circle cx="12" cy="63" r="5" code="12311" style="fill:#12311"></circle>
<circle cx="24" cy="33" r="5" code="12312" style="fill:#12311"></circle>
<circle cx="32" cy="43" r="5" code="12313" style="fill:#12311"></circle>
```

here is my search box html

```
<input type="text" id="searchBox"><input type="button" id="search" value="search"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

If your search is always a simple equivalence test against the `code` attribute, you could just use an attribute selector:

```
d3.selectAll("circle[code='12311']");
```